# Floor leveling compound mounds under the shower base -manufacturer recommendation- will they leave gaps around the base?

Tags: shower

This is a very heavy shower base and I want to make sure I am doing this right there won't be a lot of room to maneuver after I put the shower base in
Below are their instructions.

My  question is this: *Since the purpose of this is to allow the installer to set the base level I assume this might leave me with some room between the floor and the shower base.*
**Will this practically float the shower base?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No floor is expected to be perfect level without extra efforts (apply levelling grout for instance). The mounts are designed to be fool proof (for uncertainty of floor levelness), and to ensure the shower base ends up in a leveled position, without overstress/distort the base from localized loss in contact due to floor irregularity.

Hope this helps you to make decision.

Comment: you got me wrong sorry if I was not clear, by floating I meant keep it level. I am being told that the above is a quick fix for a floor that is not level but if the floor is level you should not need those mounds. I am tempted to believe that they are to stabilize and prevent lateral movements ..the base will sink into mounds and reach the floor level anyway but the mounds will get into the profiles of the back side of the shower base and will prevent the lateral moves

Comment: No floor is expected to be 100% level without extra works (apply levelling grout for instance), the mounts are rightfully recommended to cover all circumstances, and save the manufacturer from liability issues. My suggestion is to follow the instruction, so the finger may never pointing to you by not following the manufacturer's instruction, shall anything goes wrong. You need to reframe your question around your main concerns, in order to draw more accurate responses. Good luck.